# Why is using 'C.object.data.uv_layers.remove()' in a loop not removing all UV layers?

Tags: python, scripting, uv

After hours of arguing with my code (Trying to eliminate some uv_layers), I'm trying this script directly in the console:

```
for uv in C.object.data.uv_layers:
    C.object.data.uv_layers.remove(uv)
```

This is producing unexpected results, including partial, but not complete, deletion of all uv_layers (Uv Map)
I would have expected all maps to be deleted.
In addition in some cases I get strange errors, with uv_layers names that are not even present in the C.object.data.uv_layers list.

I would like to be sure that we are talking about a bug, in this case I would eliminate the question right away.
If not, I'd like to know if I'm doing something wrong.

A simple test is to add a dozen or more uv_layers, manually, and run this code
The result:
[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Try a while loop.**

Rather than looping thru a list you are removing from, it is often a better to make a copy of that list and pop and remove until list exhausted.

Using `pop()` is taking from the end of the list.

```
>>> me = C.object.data
>>> me
bpy.data.meshes['Suzanne']


>>> uvlayers = me.uv_layers[:]
>>> while uvlayers:
...     me.uv_layers.remove(uvlayers.pop())
```

Comment: so I guess this is another example in which it is a bad idea to mutate a list that is currently iterated over. More like a generic Python topic than a Blender specific one, right?

Comment: Ok, this seems to work fine, but how can I avoid deleting a certain uv_layers? assuming that a me.uv_layers['My uv map'] must remain on the list?

Comment: @aliasguru Pretty much.  When iterating as in question code I often get eg  `RuntimeError: Error: Texture layer 'UVMap.003' not found`  Appears blender is resetting the active index and possibly reordering the list in doing so.  I use "while pop" by default.   @N

Comment: @NoobCat remove any not to be removed from list copy. `uv_layers`.

Answer (score 3):

Other solution (for completeness) is to walk the list from last element to first one with a for loop. It is more error-prone than copying the full list as suggested by the other answer. Moreover since there will be at most 8 UV Maps the potential speed gain is null.

```
import bpy

layers = bpy.context.object.data.uv_layers

for uv_layer in reversed(layers):
    layers.remove(uv_layer)
```

Comment: Right, I hadn't thought about it, I was aware of it, but it escaped me.
Sounds like a good observation.